# Filtering an array based on an Inner array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to refactor my code in order to avoid doing new http requests to my api anytime I want to filter results.

So I have this array `pageContent` which gets data from an API fetch at page load.
It is composed of several object like the one below:

```
{
"title": "some title",
"description": "some random description",
"tags": [
         "Tag1",
         "Tag2",
         "Tag3"
        ]
}
```

What I am trying to do is to filter this array if a certain filter button is clicked.
This filter button emits a string as value that is then passed into the filter function.
So this is what I have now:

```
this.pageContent.filter(element => {
  //ref is the string value that is emmited by the filter button
  return element.tags.includes(ref)
})
```

Unfortunately this is not working, and the array always shows exactly the same..

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to `.filter` returns a new array, it does not modify `this.pageContent` in-place. So:

```
this.pageContent = this.pageContent.filter(element => {
  //ref is the string value that is emmited by the filter button
  return element.tags.includes(ref)
})
```